# mvn dependency:tree fails on multi-module project due to range version confict

Tags: maven-3

I have a multi-module Maven project. The parent pom contains two modules:

- `moduleA` (POM)
- `moduleB` (POM)

`moduleA.pom` contains three modules:

- `moduleC` (JAR)
- `moduleD` (JAR)
- `moduleE` (WAR)

`moduleB` depends on C, D and E.

`mvn clean package -DskipTests` and `mvn clean install -DskipTests` runs fine but when I ran `mvn dependency:tree` after these commands, I faced version conflict error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project moduleB: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.org:moduleB:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for com.org:moduleB:pom:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not resolve version conflict among [com.org:moduleC:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> com.org:test:jar:[1.0.0,1.1.0), com.org:moduleD:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> com.org:test:jar:[1.0.0,2.0.0), com.org:moduleE:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT -> com.org:test:jar:[1.1.0,2.0.0)] -> [Help 1]

module C, D and E are not under my control to change above versioning.

I tried some solutions as mentioned here without any success:

[mvn dependency:tree fails on trivial project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835418/mvn-dependencytree-fails-on-trivial-project)

Comment: Following links could help - https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/resolve-ranges.html and https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/resolve-ranges-mojo.html

Comment: You could also try referring this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28835418/mvn-dependencytree-fails-on-trivial-project